# how to read data from MYSQL in flutter

Tags: mysql, database, flutter, dart

i want to read all data from table "add_news".the code is given below

```
var db =  Mysql();
  void _getnews() async{
    await db.getConnection().then((conn) async{

      //           the select query
      String sql = "select * from add_news;";
      await conn.query(sql).then((results) {
        for(var row in results){
          print(row);

        }
      });
      conn.close();
    });
  }
```

can some please tell me how can i do this??

Comment: You question is unclear.You appear to be asking a question that the code already provided the solution to

Comment: sorry,but i wrote these code and error is its not working,i can't fetch data by using these code

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information if you want people to help you. You need to be explicit about what you are trying to do, what you expect the outcome to be and what is actually happening. If its an error then you should generally provide the stacktrace and the error message. A minimal code example that reproduces the problem is also ideal but not always practical.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show inside your flutter app, then try this.
Display it using future builder. And also make a Model of your database

Repo [Link](https://github.com/ayoubzulfiqar/flutter_with_mysql)

```dart
Future<List<Profiles>> getSQLData() async {
    final List<Profiles> profileList = [];
    final Mysql db = Mysql();
    await db.getConnection().then((conn) async {
      String sqlQuery = 'select email, password from users';
      await conn.query(sqlQuery).then((results) {
        for (var res in results) {
          final profileModel =
              Profiles(email: res["email"], password: res["password"]);

          profileList.add(profileModel);
        }
      }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
        print(error);
        return null;
      });
      conn.close();
    });

    return profileList;
  }
```